# Is 'git rm' the canonical response to 'deleted by us' if the file should be deleted?

Tags: git, github, git-merge

Let's consider this short git scenario:

```
(master)>echo 1 > a.txt
(master)>git add a.txt
(master)>git commit -m "Commit 0"
(master)>git checkout -b b
(b)>git rm a.txt
(b)>git commit -m "Deleted a.txt"
(b)>git checkout master
(master)>echo 2 > a.txt
(master)>git commit -am "Modified a.txt"
(master)>git checkout b
(b)>git merge master
CONFLICT (modify/delete): a.txt deleted in HEAD and modified in master. Version master of a.txt left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

The satus at this point is:

```
(b|MERGING)>git status
On branch b
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

        deleted by us:   a.txt
```

My way of resolving this is to `git rm a.txt`. This will give me what I need but, is this **the** way to deal with this? In other words is there a more expressive way (something like git merge accept_delete) to deal with this?

(`git checkout a.txt --ours` wouldn't work because a.txt doesn't exist on `our` side)

Comment: I also prefer `git rm` as I know exactly what I am doing. It is worth noting the existence of `git merge strategy-option=ours` that take always the changes from your branch. But it erases any change from master when merging on b if I understand it well.

Comment: You can check https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies if you're curious about other strategies (they seem pretty specific though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git rm` is my preferred method.  Git itself doesn't care *how* you produce the result, though; it only cares that you put the right resolution into your *index*.  It's usually good to make your work-tree reflect your index too, but Git doesn't care about that: that's just for your own sanity.

In this particular state, the file `a.txt` appears in index slots 1 and 3, and not in index slot 2.  The version of `a.txt` in slot 1 is the copy taken from the merge base.  The version in slot 3 is the copy taken from the tip of `master`.  This `master` version of `a.txt` appears in the work-tree as well.

Using:

```
rm a.txt
git add a.txt
```

will erase `a.txt` from the work-tree first, then also erase it from index slots 1 and 3, leaving no `a.txt` at all in the index, which is the state you want.  But the simpler:

```
git rm a.txt
```

will erase `a.txt` from the work-tree and from index slots 1 and 3, producing exactly the same result.

All *Git* cares about is what's in the index.  Files in slot-zero entries—you can see them with `git ls-files --stage`, although if you have a lot of files, the amount of text this prints is daunting—will be in the next commit.  Files in slots 1, 2, and/or 3 are in "conflicted" state.  These need to be cleared out before `git commit`, or anything else that makes a commit, can proceed.

Both `git add` and `git rm` knock out the conflicted-state entries, so either method is fine, but it feels weird to me to `git add` a file that doesn't exist—you have to remove it first for this case, and then it just feels weird.